# Applying Time series models for each row

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe (df), which is wide dataset with the following structure,

```
ID 2015/01/01 2015/02/01 2015/03/01 2015/04/01
A1 42         42        24          32 
A2 22         22        24          32 
A3 12         15        19          22 
A4 8          12        18          24
```

- I want to build time series model for each row, thus there will be N
  time series model where N = number of rows in dataframe

**I tired the following:**

```
ts_1 <-  ts(df[1:1,], start = c(2015, 05), frequency = 12)

ts_1_stl <- stl(ts_1, s.window = "periodic")
```

**But I got the error as :**

```
Error in stl(ts_1, s.window = "periodic") : only univariate series are allowed
```

- What am I doing wrong, how can I apply to every row

Comment: I guess first statement would be `ts(unlist(df[-1]), start = c(2015, 05), frequency = 12)` or if you want it for each row `apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) ts(x, start = c(2015, 05), frequency = 12))`

Comment: It worked thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are applying on each row (the first column is 'ID', a character class column, which is not needed), we can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) ts(x, start = c(2015, 05), frequency = 12))
```

For the whole dataset, we need to `unlist`

```
ts(unlist(df[-1]), start = c(2015, 05), frequency = 12)
```

---

We would assume the 'df' to have more number of columns to have enough observations i.e. at least 2 periods for the "periodic" to work

```
set.seed(24)
df <- cbind(Col1 = LETTERS[1:4], as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(31*4), ncol=31)))
res <- apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) stl(ts(x, start = c(2015, 05),
           frequency = 12), s.window = "periodic"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I up voted for the res <- apply of stl. Cant thank you enough!